# Can UTF8 encoded data missread as Latin-1 produce ASCII artifacts?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, sanitization

UTF-8 single byte characters map perfectly to Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) characters (those below the character code of 128); basicly the default ASCII characters.
If I have a UTF-8 encoded string and pass it to a function, that expects a Latin-1 string is there any possibility that the Latin-1 function misinterprets parts of UTF-8 mutlibyte characters as ASCII characters?

I imagine something like this *could* happen:

(imagniray) UTF-8 multibyte character: `0xA330`
(mis-)interpreted by Latin-1 function as two Latin-1 characters: `0xA3` `0x30`

The first of those characters does not lie within the ASCII set, but the second is the ASCII code for the 0 character. Is it possible that an multibyte UTF-8 character produces an artifact that looks like a single-byte UTF-8 / ASCII character like in the example above?

From my understanding of UTF-8 only single-byte characters contain any bytes with the most significant bit unset, so basicly multibyte characters never contain a byte that could be misinterpreted by a Latin-1 function as a valid ASCII character (because all those characters have the most significant bit unset). But I want to make sure this is true and I don't screw up on this, because this may have security implications when dealing with data sanitization - which I am apparently currently doing.

Comment: You pretty much answered the question yourself, and I think your reasoning is correct, assuming that it's a valid UTF8 string. Obviously users/hackers might input invalid strings like the 0xA330 in your example.

Comment: I am aware of this of course. My issue is more that I have to use a function that expects Latin-1 and was going to transform my UTF-8 string to a Latin-1 representation first, but due to how UTF-8 seperates single from multibyte characters and since the valid characters for the string all lie within the ASCII page there's actually no need to do that transformation step without having to fear "valid" artifacts appearing from a invalid UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding that only single byte characters contain any bytes with the most significant bit unset. There is a nice table showing this at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Comment: So there is no way a single byte from a multibyte character could be misinterpreted as an ASCII character because they all have values of at least 128?

Comment: That would be my understanding, yes. When UTF-8 multibyte characters get misinterpreted as Latin-1 the come out as a mess of accented characters.

Comment: It couldn't be misinterpreted as an ASCII character, but it could be misinterpreted as an ISO 8859-1 character. If your sanitization proceeds on the assumption that it's dealing with ISO 8859-1 input and tries to do something like strip diacriticals (å -> a), instead of discarding any non-ASCII input, things could get weird.